# Algorithm to find the largest integer in array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, integer

I am trying to create a method which returns an int - the value of the largest integer in the sent array.
The way I want this method to work, is to check the first **and** the last element of the array in a for-loop, and work their way to the middle. So i = first integer, k = last integer. When `i = 0, k = n-1` (indexes), when `i = 1, k = n-2` if you catch my drift. In every loop it needs to check `if a[i]>a[k]`. Then they switch places. Then I know that the largest number is in the leading half of the array, and then I want it to check that half, so ultimately the largest int is at index 0.

I tried like this:

```
public static int maxOfArray(int[] a)
{
    int length = a.length;

    if(length<1)
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Not at least one integer in array");

    while (length > 1)
    {
        int k = length;

        for(int i = 0; i < length/2; i++)
        {
            k--;

            if(a[i]<a[k])
            {
                int j = a[i];
                a[i] = a[k];
                a[k] = j;
            }
        }
        length /=2;
    }
    return a[0];
}
```

..but I don't really get it.. I'm having a hard time "picturing" what's happening here.. But it's not always working.. (though sometimes).

**EDIT**
Also: The array {6,15,2,5,8,14,10,16,11,17,13,7,1,18,3,4,9,12}; will spit out 17 as the largest number. I realize I have to fix the odd-length bug, but I would like to solve this even-length array first..

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reason why you are trying such a complex method where a linear scan does the trick? Is it HW? example from a book? interview? It might help us give you better focused answers.

Comment: "[...] Then they switch places" - looks like the OP actually wants to *sort* the array in some bubble sort style. Please add the _quiz_ tag!

Comment: @amit Well, yes. This is to a little school project. I can see many answers with other methods, but the request is to compare the first and the last, then switch places if the last is bigger - then continue towards the middle of the array. The biggest is not to be placed in index 0, just placed on the "left" side of the array, thus placing it on index 0 when the time comes..

Comment: The largest would not always be in the leading half. Say you array is [1, 5, 3], then you first compare (1 > 3), then (5 > 5) and lastly (3 > 1). You now have [3, 5, 1] and you divide the length by 2 which gives you the array [3]. You lost the 5. Also, if you switch the comparison you don't have to scan the whole array, only half. Now you first move large numbers to the upper half, then back to the lower.

Comment: For easier debugging, output the array after each switch and each loop .

Comment: So `for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)` is wrong, you only need to iterate over the first half of the array: `for(int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)`. Also check what happens if the array size is odd.

Comment: @f_puras: This is an answer. post it (or with your premission I can add it to my answer). I believe this with addition to the odd-length issue I mentioned is pretty much the issue, unless I am missing something else :|

Comment: @amit Please feel free to update your answer! It's all [CC BY-SA](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing) ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A bug is when encountering `length` is odd.**

In these cases, you "miss" the middle element.

**Example**: for input `int[] arr = { 8, 1, 5, 4, 9, 4, 3, 7, 2 };` - the element `9` will be compared and checked against itself, but then you reduce the size of `length`, you exclude `9` from the array you are going to iterate next.

I believe it can be solved by reducing the problem to `ceil(length/2)` instead of `length/2` (and handling special case of `length==1`)

The other issue as was mentioned in comments is: you need to **iterate up to `length/2`** rather then up to `length`, otherwise you are overriding yourself.

Lastly - **the sign is wrong**.

```
if(a[i]>a[k])
```

should be

```
if(a[i]<a[k])
```

Remember - you are trying to swap the elements if the first is smaller the the second in order to push the larger elements to the head of your array.

Comment: Thank you, I now realize that an odd-length would damage this, however, I am testing my method with different arrays, some of them working, and the one (so far) that failed was an even-length array = {6,15,2,5,8,14,10,16,11,17,13,7,1,18,3,4,9,12} setting 17 at the index 0, even though 18 is larger.

Comment: @StianF: I believe f_puras's is also correct in his comment. You should iterate up to `length/2` in addition to what I mentioned here.

Comment: @StianF: Here you go - the if condition sign is also wrong. I editted the answer to reflect it.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, forgot to change the question. That however, did not solve my problem.. I will update my question.

Comment: That is weird.. When I try the array {6,15,2,5,8,14,10,16,11,17,13,7,1,18,3,4,9,12};, and print it out after the method I get: 17,16,10,14,18,5,4,15,12,11,13,7,1,8,3,2,9,6..

Comment: @StianF: Did you fix the odd array length issue? It may occure even for even length array, because you constantly divide the problem (For example length=18, the second iteration will have length=9)

Comment: You can fix it by: `length = (int)Math.ceil((double)length/2);` for the modification of `length`.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. Beating myself up for not realizing that an even array would possibly eventually become an odd array when dividing it.

Answer (score 3):

> but I don't really get it.. I'm having a hard time "picturing" what's happening here.. But it's not always working.. (though sometimes).

In that case you should use a debugger to step through the code to get a picture of what each line of code does.

---

What I would do is:

```
public static int maxOfArray(int[] a) {
    int max = a[0];
    for (int i : a)
        if (max < i)
            max = i;
    return max;
}

public static int findMaxTheHardWay(int[] array) {
    for (int length = array.length; length > 1; length = (length + 1) / 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
            if (array[i] < array[length - i - 1])
                array[i] = array[length - i - 1]; // don't need to swap.
        }
    }
    return array[0];
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Random rand = new Random(1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        int[] a = new int[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) a[j] = rand.nextInt();
        int max = maxOfArray(a);
        int max2 = findMaxTheHardWay(a);
        if (max != max2)
            throw new AssertionError(i + ": " + max + " != " + max2);
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not answer the OPs question. `The way I want this method to work, is to....`

Comment: @amit Added a solution for finding the max the hard way. ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is rather a crazy way to solve the problem, but I'll play along.

The problem is in the inner loop.

- You start out with i = 0 and k = length - 1.
- If a[i] > a[k] you swap them.
- ...
- You end up with k = 0 and i = length - 1
- If a[i] > a[k] you swap them.

If you look at that carefully you will notice that if we swapped the elements in the first swap, we will also swap them in the last swap; i.e. we will UNDO the effects of the first swap.  And the same applies pair-wise through the entire array slice.

See?

What you need to do is to stop the inner loop half way ... and then take account of the case where `length` is odd.

---

By the way, the reason I called this "rather crazy", because the obvious and simple way is much faster: `O(N)` versus `O(NlogN)`

Comment: Thanks! However, theres still something wrong.. May be something else from my stupid code, but I have now stopped the loop half way `i<length/2`, and I have also realized that I actually swapped the larger integer to the wrong half, but I still get wrong with certain arrays. I.e 6,15,2,5,8,14,10,16,11,17,13,7,1,18,3,4,9,12. I have not started on the odd-length as this is an even length not yet working..

Comment: Yea, if you are shuffling large numbers to the left you gave got the sign of your comparison the wrong way around.

Comment: If you still can't figure out what the problem in your code is, try adding traceprints or running it using a debugger.

Comment: We figured it out. amit was right. The problem was that I didn't take account of the odd-length arrays. I stupidly chose not to do it, because I got the wrong output when using an even-length array, but as the length of that array was `18`, it would have an odd-length `9` in the second turn.  Btw, how do I figure out the 0(NlogN) stuff? And what is it called in english?

Comment: @Stainf - In english, it is called "complexity analysis", and that is 
"Big O" or "Landau" notation.  Wait until they teach it to you, or look it up on Wikipedia :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[] = {1,7,3};   
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(a);  
Integer largest = Collections.max(list);
```

This will give you Largest number in Array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that fits the specifications that you want (unlike many other here, humm, humm):

```
    final Integer[] input = {1, 2, 6, 32, 4, 44 ,12, 42, 3, 7, 17, 22, 57, 23, 102, 103 };

    int half = (input.length / 2);
    int mod = input.length % 2;
    while (half >= 0) {
        for (int i = 0, j = (half * 2) + mod - 1; i <= half && j >= half; i++, j--) {
            if (input[i] < input[j]) {
                final int tmp = input[i];
                input[i] = input[j];
                input[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
        if (half == 0) break;
        half = half / 2;
        mod = half % 2;
    }
    //Here, input[0] = the biggest number in the original input.
```

Edit: Added mod, so it works if the last element is the largest..

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is working, you just have to ceil the length / 2 in case of odd array but my tests return proper result:

```
package org.devince.largestinteger;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class LargestInteger {
    final static int[] input = {1, 2, 6, 32, 4, 44 ,12, 42, 3, 7, 17, 22, 57, 23, 102, 103 };
//  final static int[] input = { 8, 1, 5, 4, 9, 4, 3, 7, 2 };
//  final static int[] input = {1,3,7};

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(maxOfArray(input)));
    }

    public static int maxOfArray(int[] a)
    {
        int length = a.length;

        if(length<1)
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Not at least one integer in array");

        while (length > 1)
        {
            int k = length;

            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                k--;

                if(a[i]>a[k])
                {
                    int j = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[k];
                    a[k] = j;
                }
            }
            length = (int) Math.ceil(length / 2f);
        }
        return a[0];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store the first value of the array to a variable `max`.

After that just loop through the array starting from second position till the last ,
in the loop just check if the current value is greater than `max` or not.If it is greater just assign `max` that value.

Return `max` and you have the largest number.

```
public int FindLargest()
{
    int[] num = { 1, 2, 5, 12, 13, 56, 16, 4 };
    int max = num[0];

    for (int i = 1; i <num.length; i++)
    {
        if (num[i] > max)
        {
            max = num[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: (1) it does not answer the OPs question. `The way I want this method to work, is to....`  (2) it is not java (`Length` field). C# I suspect

Comment: @amit Ok it doesnot answer OPs question but provides an alternative that works.Why not?

Comment: @amit `num.length` is perfectly right, check [Java Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950155) for an SO example.

Comment: @f_puras It was `num.Length` when this comment was added ;)

Comment: @freebird `num.length` is correct, `num.Length` is incorrect. Why change it back?

Answer (score 0):

As the same u can approach like also,

```
int length = a.length;
   while (length > 1)
    {
        int k = length;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        { 
            for(int y = k-1; y >= i; y--) 
            {         
                if(a[i]<a[y])
                {
                    int j = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[y];
                    a[y] = j;               
                }
            }       
        }
        length /=2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         final int validSampleRates[] = new int[]{
                    5644800, 2822400, 352800, 192000, 176400, 96000,
                    88200, 50400, 50000, 4800,47250, 44100, 44056, 37800, 32000, 22050, 16000, 11025, 4800, 8000};
          ArrayList <Integer> YourArray = new ArrayList <Integer> ():
 for (int smaple : validSampleRates){

                    YourArray.add(smaple);
                }
            Integer largest = Collections.max(YourArray);
            System.out.println("Largest   " + String.valueOf(largest));
```

**The best way is to use Array that extends List Collection as ArrayList**