# length in arrays and length() in String

Tags: java, arrays, string

Why is **length** a data field in when we talk about arrays and **length()** when we talk about String in Java? Means:

```
int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
String str = "foo";
int a_len = a.length;
int str_len = str.length();
```

Why is length not a function in case of arrays or vice versa?

Comment: likely because the array length is stored as part of the array object, and the string length isn't and would need to be calculated.

Comment: @Shmiddty -- Actually, the string length is stored.

Comment: @Shmiddty: since java's strings are immutable, the value could be cached.

Comment: Also discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950155/java-arrays-length

Comment: function call needs time, it's not reasonable. why strings don't have such field?

Comment: @HotLicks I was just speculating (which is why I didn't post it as an answer).

Comment: @Shmiddty -- Well, you may be partly true -- it's possible that early on, in version 0.0.1 or whatever, String.length() required computation, and the concept "stuck".  But as of versions 1.2 - 5.0, when I was working in the innards of Java, the length of a String object was always stored in the object as a simple int field.

Comment: @HotLicks So likely it's related to backwards compatibility?

Comment: @Shmiddty -- It's definitely backward compatibility.  And maybe a few egos.

Comment: Another question is why the same concept is called "size" in other contexts.  Lots of inconsistency.

Comment: @HotLicks That's a nice question too. Do you have an answer for that too?

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal -- That I'd ascribe to carelessness early on.

Comment: *Everybody* here is speculating. The answer is "because that's the way Gosling *et al.* designed it". Not much point in asking here: you will get guesswork and if you're lucky some valid *post hoc* reasoning. You're asking in the wrong place. Not constructive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply: that's just the way it is, and the way it's always been.

It's specified in [JLS section 10.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7) that arrays have a public final `length` field. It could have been specified as a method instead, for consistency - but it just wasn't... equally `String` *could* have made an implementation decision to have a public final `length` field - but again, it happens not to be that way.

There are a few bits of inconsistency which have survived since 1.0 - obviously these things really can't be changed after release...

Comment: And since the JIT will likely inline `String:length()` anyway, there shouldn't be any difference in performance either.

Comment: Yep, I'm sure if it were done over it would be done differently.  Either make array length a method call or introduce a general scheme for read-only fields for all objects.

Comment: @jon skeet: So, didn't it occur in the next releases means they could have just added length data field to String?

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal: That would be moving away from the generally accepted best practice of separating API from implementation. The better fix would have been to introduce a `length()` method in arrays, but it would have been confusing to have both, IMO.

Comment: Ok. So i take is as this was the first implementation they came up with and didn't want to change it later. Right?

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal -- Yep.  And there are lots of things in Java (and most other languages) like that.  Java in particular has been quite rigid on it's upward compatibility points, and so many "reasonable" enhancements/changes have been rejected.

Comment: @Hot Licks Point accepted. But the thing I am confused about is that if we want to keep a language upward compatible then why do we have obsolete data types? Why not keep them?

Comment: First off, Java has only very rarely (if ever) completely eliminated a class or method -- generally they're just "deprecated" and strongly discouraged.  Secondly, the guardians of the API (and especially the API outside of the main `java.` classes) are different from the guardians of the Java Virtual Machine, bytecodes, et al.  The latter group is (usually) conservative to a fault, while the former group is often far too quick to throw in new features and options.

Answer (score 4):

`String` implements [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) and thus `length` needs to be a method in this case since interfaces can only specify methods.

Arrays don't need to implement any interface, so `length` is implemented as a public final field in this case to avoid extra method call overhead.

**Edit:**

As Hot Licks pointed out below, `CharSequence` didn't exist before Java 1.4. Although CharSequence obviously wasn't the driving reason behind this design choice (since it didn't exist), it would still make sense to choose this design with the idea that String might need to implement new interfaces in the future.

Comment: There was no such thing as `CharSequence` when this decision was made.

Comment: @HotLicks - That's a really good point, and it's evidenced by the 1.2 docs for [String](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs368/JavaTutorial/jdk1.2/api/java/lang/String.html). Although CharSequence didn't exist at the time, the ability to use `length` in a future interface could very well have played a role in the decision. I'll update my answer though.

Comment: A bigger question is why Java didn't implement a base class for String-like objects and make String a subclass.  CharSequence is a weak attempt to recover from this oversight.

Answer (score 0):

It's considered a variable and not a method. It would be as if you made a class and said Public static int num and later in a method told that num to be equal to something globally