# Length of an object array

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Arrays - length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950155/java-arrays-length)

How do you determine the length of an array that is not an String array or an integer array? It won't let me use `.length()`, but only `.length`?

Why and is there another way of determining this?

Comment: I think this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950155/java-arrays-length

Comment: + 1 fatfreddy, I was commenting with that link ;) You could determine most data type array (char, string, object, int) length using `Length` property of array object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays in Java are not resizable. Once an array is instantiated, its length cannot change. That's why the `length` attribute (`myArray.length`) can always be trusted to contain the array's length.

Comment: Array in Java is NOT immutable.  It is just not resizable.  Consider an array being a construct that holds multiple values/object-references, immutable will means once it is instantiated, we cannot change the values it is storing.  However it is not the case.  We can always do `myArray[2] = whatever;`.

Comment: @AdrianShum thank you, corrected wrong choice of words.

Comment: Is the `myArray.length()` refers to how many items are in the array?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `getLength` method from `java.lang.reflect.Array`, which uses reflection (so it'll be slow):

```java
Object[] anArray = new Object[2];
int length = Array.getLength(anArray);
```

Answer (score 8):

We only have `.length` but NOT `.length()`, regardless of the type of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, array `length` is not a method. But you still use that to determine the length of an array.

Are you saying that `myArray.length()` works for `String` or `int`/`Integer` array?

Anyway, when using array in Java, always consider if using `ArrayList` would suit your purpose better.

Edit: copying the useful SO link from comment of @fatfredyy to be in an answer: [How is length implemented in Java Arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950155/java-arrays-length?lq=1)