# Code will not compile, as it's "too large", even though the entire class is just data

Tags: java, arrays, constants

I'm using NetBeans 8.1, trying to create a 2D array of impulse filters, each of which is an array of 128 doubles.  I've generated text like this:
(Note that I've replaced most of the double[] values with ... to make it easier to read).

There are about 380 of these:

```
double[]  left_H80e000a={0.1250000,-0.0390930,0.1328125...,0.7511292};
double[]  left_H80e030a={-0.0390930,0.1406250,-0.0390930,...0.7511292};


double[][][] left_filters={
     {left_H_40e000a,null,left_H_40e006a,left_H_40e013a,left_H_40e019a,null,left_H_40e026a,left_H_40e032a,left_H_40e039a,left_H_40e045a,null,left_H_40e051a,left_H_40e058a,left_H_40e064a,null,left_H_40e071a,left_H_40e077a,left_H_40e084a,left_H_40e090a,null,left_H_40e096a,left_H_40e103a,left_H_40e109a,null,left_H_40e116a,left_H_40e122a,left_H_40e129a,left_H_40e135a,null,left_H_40e141a,left_H_40e148a,left_H_40e154a,null,left_H_40e161a,left_H_40e167a,left_H_40e174a,left_H_40e180a}
    ,{left_H_30e000a,null,left_H_30e006a,left_H_30e012a,left_H_30e018a,left_H_30e024a,left_H_30e030a,null,left_H_30e036a,left_H_30e042a,left_H_30e048a,left_H_30e054a,left_H_30e060a,null,left_H_30e066a,left_H_30e072a,left_H_30e078a,left_H_30e084a,left_H_30e090a,null,left_H_30e096a,left_H_30e102a,left_H_30e108a,left_H_30e114a,left_H_30e120a,null,left_H_30e126a,left_H_30e132a,left_H_30e138a,left_H_30e144a,left_H_30e150a,null,left_H_30e156a,left_H_30e162a,left_H_30e168a,left_H_30e174a,left_H_30e180a}
    ,{left_H_20e000a,left_H_20e005a,left_H_20e010a,left_H_20e015a,left_H_20e020a,left_H_20e025a,left_H_20e030a,left_H_20e035a,left_H_20e040a,left_H_20e045a,left_H_20e050a,left_H_20e055a,left_H_20e060a,left_H_20e065a,left_H_20e070a,left_H_20e075a,left_H_20e080a,left_H_20e085a,left_H_20e090a,left_H_20e095a,left_H_20e100a,left_H_20e105a,left_H_20e110a,left_H_20e115a,left_H_20e120a,left_H_20e125a,left_H_20e130a,left_H_20e135a,left_H_20e140a,left_H_20e145a,left_H_20e150a,left_H_20e155a,left_H_20e160a,left_H_20e165a,left_H_20e170a,left_H_20e175a,left_H_20e180a}
    ,{left_H_10e000a,left_H_10e005a,left_H_10e010a,left_H_10e015a,left_H_10e020a,left_H_10e025a,left_H_10e030a,left_H_10e035a,left_H_10e040a,left_H_10e045a,left_H_10e050a,left_H_10e055a,left_H_10e060a,left_H_10e065a,left_H_10e070a,left_H_10e075a,left_H_10e080a,left_H_10e085a,left_H_10e090a,left_H_10e095a,left_H_10e100a,left_H_10e105a,left_H_10e110a,left_H_10e115a,left_H_10e120a,left_H_10e125a,left_H_10e130a,left_H_10e135a,left_H_10e140a,left_H_10e145a,left_H_10e150a,left_H_10e155a,left_H_10e160a,left_H_10e165a,left_H_10e170a,left_H_10e175a,left_H_10e180a}
    ,{left_H0e000a,left_H0e005a,left_H0e010a,left_H0e015a,left_H0e020a,left_H0e025a,left_H0e030a,left_H0e035a,left_H0e040a,left_H0e045a,left_H0e050a,left_H0e055a,left_H0e060a,left_H0e065a,left_H0e070a,left_H0e075a,left_H0e080a,left_H0e085a,left_H0e090a,left_H0e095a,left_H0e100a,left_H0e105a,left_H0e110a,left_H0e115a,left_H0e120a,left_H0e125a,left_H0e130a,left_H0e135a,left_H0e140a,left_H0e145a,left_H0e150a,left_H0e155a,left_H0e160a,left_H0e165a,left_H0e170a,left_H0e175a,left_H0e180a}
    ,{left_H10e000a,left_H10e005a,left_H10e010a,left_H10e015a,left_H10e020a,left_H10e025a,left_H10e030a,left_H10e035a,left_H10e040a,left_H10e045a,left_H10e050a,left_H10e055a,left_H10e060a,left_H10e065a,left_H10e070a,left_H10e075a,left_H10e080a,left_H10e085a,left_H10e090a,left_H10e095a,left_H10e100a,left_H10e105a,left_H10e110a,left_H10e115a,left_H10e120a,left_H10e125a,left_H10e130a,left_H10e135a,left_H10e140a,left_H10e145a,left_H10e150a,left_H10e155a,left_H10e160a,left_H10e165a,left_H10e170a,left_H10e175a,left_H10e180a}
    ,{left_H20e000a,left_H20e005a,left_H20e010a,left_H20e015a,left_H20e020a,left_H20e025a,left_H20e030a,left_H20e035a,left_H20e040a,left_H20e045a,left_H20e050a,left_H20e055a,left_H20e060a,left_H20e065a,left_H20e070a,left_H20e075a,left_H20e080a,left_H20e085a,left_H20e090a,left_H20e095a,left_H20e100a,left_H20e105a,left_H20e110a,left_H20e115a,left_H20e120a,left_H20e125a,left_H20e130a,left_H20e135a,left_H20e140a,left_H20e145a,left_H20e150a,left_H20e155a,left_H20e160a,left_H20e165a,left_H20e170a,left_H20e175a,left_H20e180a}
    ,{left_H30e000a,null,left_H30e006a,left_H30e012a,left_H30e018a,left_H30e024a,left_H30e030a,null,left_H30e036a,left_H30e042a,left_H30e048a,left_H30e054a,left_H30e060a,null,left_H30e066a,left_H30e072a,left_H30e078a,left_H30e084a,left_H30e090a,null,left_H30e096a,left_H30e102a,left_H30e108a,left_H30e114a,left_H30e120a,null,left_H30e126a,left_H30e132a,left_H30e138a,left_H30e144a,left_H30e150a,null,left_H30e156a,left_H30e162a,left_H30e168a,left_H30e174a,left_H30e180a}
    ,{left_H40e000a,null,left_H40e006a,left_H40e013a,left_H40e019a,null,left_H40e026a,left_H40e032a,left_H40e039a,left_H40e045a,null,left_H40e051a,left_H40e058a,left_H40e064a,null,left_H40e071a,left_H40e077a,left_H40e084a,left_H40e090a,null,left_H40e096a,left_H40e103a,left_H40e109a,null,left_H40e116a,left_H40e122a,left_H40e129a,left_H40e135a,null,left_H40e141a,left_H40e148a,left_H40e154a,null,left_H40e161a,left_H40e167a,left_H40e174a,left_H40e180a}
    ,{left_H50e000a,null,left_H50e008a,null,left_H50e016a,left_H50e024a,null,left_H50e032a,left_H50e040a,null,left_H50e048a,null,left_H50e056a,left_H50e064a,null,left_H50e072a,left_H50e080a,null,left_H50e088a,null,left_H50e096a,left_H50e104a,null,left_H50e112a,left_H50e120a,null,left_H50e128a,null,left_H50e136a,left_H50e144a,null,left_H50e152a,left_H50e160a,null,left_H50e168a,null,left_H50e176a}
    ,{left_H60e000a,null,left_H60e010a,null,left_H60e020a,null,left_H60e030a,null,left_H60e040a,null,left_H60e050a,null,left_H60e060a,null,left_H60e070a,null,left_H60e080a,null,left_H60e090a,null,left_H60e100a,null,left_H60e110a,null,left_H60e120a,null,left_H60e130a,null,left_H60e140a,null,left_H60e150a,null,left_H60e160a,null,left_H60e170a,null,left_H60e180a}
    ,{left_H70e000a,null,null,left_H70e015a,null,null,left_H70e030a,null,null,left_H70e045a,null,null,left_H70e060a,null,null,left_H70e075a,null,null,left_H70e090a,null,null,left_H70e105a,null,null,left_H70e120a,null,null,left_H70e135a,null,null,left_H70e150a,null,null,left_H70e165a,null,null,left_H70e180a}
    ,{left_H80e000a,null,null,null,null,null,left_H80e030a,null,null,null,null,null,left_H80e060a,null,null,null,null,null,left_H80e090a,null,null,null,null,null,left_H80e120a,null,null,null,null,null,left_H80e150a,null,null,null,null,null,left_H80e180a}
    ,{left_H90e000a,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null}
};
```

I've had much larger arrays in past code, one of which is 26 arrays containing 60,000 strings, so I'm baffled as to why this isn't possible.

Firstly, **there's no code**, secondly, does anyone have a better way to embed large data structures in Java?

Comment: Could you load most of that data from a database instead?

Comment: There's "no code"? Where do you think all that data ends up? What do you think it *is*?

Comment: I'm with JAB...what you're doing here seems like something that would be best handled by a db fetch.

Comment: write it to a file type of your choice and parse it in during runtime. What is the actually error you get? Is it complaining that the file is too large, or a particular structure in the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maximum size of java class / exception table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497495/maximum-size-of-java-class-exception-table)

Comment: Please post the error/exception you're getting. What version of Java are you using? Have you tried compiling outside the IDE, i.e. from the command line?

Comment: I could probably load it from a text file, but that's not the simplest solution, since I'd have to bind the names to the data manually.  Not a big deal, but programming languages are supposed to make life easier, not harder ;-)  The error message is just "code too large", I don't know which version of Java it is; but I believe it's the latest.  As to "there's no code" - what I expected from a modern compiler is that it would put constant data in a separate data area, since anything else would be madness.

Comment: @user3660664 It still goes into the class file, because it's in the class. There are a list of absolute constraints the JVM operates under, many of which have to do with the size of things, e.g., https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11. (There are other limitations as well, but that's a starting point for your exploration.)

Comment: Thank you for that.   I still can't what the compiler's complaining about though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well there is code. This is converted to bytecode, somewhere the JVM will have to load these number in memory, you can have a guess as what the code will look like here: [How does Arrays work in the ByteCode of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646022/how-does-arrays-work-in-the-bytecode-of-java)

The worst solution I could think of would creating one class per array (like a `Left_H80e000a` class and statically calling them for your 3D arrays.

But honestly, create a CSV file and read from it. Like, you make aleft_H80e000a.csv" with the same data, read from it then put it in your 3D array. (isn't `double[] left_H80e000a= readFromCSV("left_H80e000a.csv");` cleaner ?..) I guess a class file with only the 3D array should be fine.

Some comments stated to use a database. That's an idea, but there is no point building a database if that's your only use.

Comment: I think you're telling me it can't be done.  Fair enough, I'll do something along the lines of what you suggest.