# Why the running time complexity of (List<Object>) list.size() is O(1)?

Tags: java, time-complexity

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614298/what-is-the-runtime-of-array-length?lq=1) I understood that the complexity of some static arr is O(1)

But for dynamic array the size is never set, so how the complexity will be constant?
Even Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) says so.

```
static int count =  0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach(x -> count++); // Java-10
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

this code should determine the size of the list, if this runs for O(n) times then why

```
List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).size();
```

is O(1)

Comment: because the size is stored internally somewhere in the list object.

Comment: `List` is an interface, so whether `.size()` is O(1) or O(n) depends on the implementation.

Comment: *"But for dynamic array"* There is no such thing as a *dynamic array* in Java. Arrays always have a fixed size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're specifically asking why `List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).size()` is *O(1)*.

While other answers have correctly said that implementations such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) explicitly store the lists size as a field of the list, that doesn't actually answer your question, because [`List.of​(E... elements)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)) doesn't use those implementations.

`List.of(E... elements)` is varargs, which means that internally it is actually `List.of(E[] elements)` and the compiler builds a fixed array for you. In your case, that array is exactly 5 in size.

Although the implementation is really different, building an immutable list, the `E[]` is turned into a list similarly to how [`Arrays.asList​(T... a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) does it, i.e. by wrapping the array in a `List` implementation that uses the array directly.

As such, the list size of very well known, because the **size is the length of the backing array**.

Answer (score 5):

While forming the List the time complexity is not `O(1)`. After list is formed the size is saved internally in the list. After that when we call `List.size()` it just return the saved size with time complexity O(1)

Answer (score 4):

As per, for example, [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java), ArrayList will store the current size as to make it immediately available.  Other lists would be similar, as it's a common optimization. (Eg. [LinkedList](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java))