# Understanding Iteration with 2d arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I am watching a tutorial on 2d arrays and I can't seem to understand where the values for 
states.length and states[i].length are coming from. How does it know the outer loop deals with the size 3 array and the inner is the size 2 array?

```
public class Test3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String [][] states = new String[3][2];

    states[0][0] = "California";
    states[0][1] = "Sacremento";

    states[1][0] = "Oregon";
    states[1][1] = "Salem";

    states[2][0] = "Washington";
    states[2][1] = "Olympia";

    for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < states[i].length; j++) {

            sb.append(states[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: arr.length is a property of the array. see [this][1] post .


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950155/how-is-length-implemented-in-java-arrays

Answer (score 0):

The `states.length` is the row length of your array while the `states[i].length` is the number of column of the specified row.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a two dimensional array is an array of arrays.

So String[3][2] is

```
[["string", "string"],
 ["string", "string"],
 ["string", "string"]]
```

`states.length` is the length of the outer array, which is 3.

`states[i].length` is the length of each individual array, which are all 2.

Answer (score 0):

You begin by creating a 2D array that looks like the following.

```
[[California, Sacramento]
[Oregon, Salem]
[Washington, Olympia]]
```

The first for loop will iterate over each row.  In this case states.length is 3 because there are 3 rows.

The next for loop will iterate over the columns in each row.
In other words, `states[i]` will give you a row.  If i is 0, then `states[0]` is `[California, Sacramento]`

There are 2 entries in that row, so `states[0].length` is 2.